# Docker - Outgoing HTTPS requests timing out

Tags: docker, ssl, networking, https

I am running my app using docker-compose. The app contains many containers. One container has a node.js app and other has a .net core app. When trying to send HTTPS requests to an outside server, from any of the containers, the request's timeout.

Docker is somehow blocking outgoing HTTPS requests.

On googling, everyone suggested changing MTU, so I changed it to 1400 but still no luck.

```
networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge
    driver_opts:
      com.docker.network.driver.mtu: 1400
```

Comment: Can you install `telnet` into container and trest connection via `telnet REMOTE_ADDRESS 443`? Timeouts are typically causes by network blocking or the remote service not responding.

Answer (score 1):

Finally to get it working I had to set the mtu to 1300 in `docker-compose.yml` file. Also had to update the docker config file

`/etc/docker/daemon.json` with value `{ "mtu": 1300 }`