# Outgoing HTTP requests time out when running ASP.NET in Docker Desktop using Windows Container

Tags: c#, docker, network-programming, docker-for-windows

I am running an ASP.NET web application in Docker Desktop for the first time. I have created an ASP.NET application (targeting .NET Framework) using the standard template in Visual Studio 2019 with Docker Support.

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.7.2-windowsservercore-1803
ARG source
WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
```

**Docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  mydockerizedwebapp:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}mydockerizedwebapp
    container_name: mydockerizedwebapp
    build:
      context: .\MyDockerizedWebApp
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

**Docker-compose.override.yml:**

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  mydockerizedwebapp:
    ports:
      - "80"
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nat
```

I have installed Docker Desktop on my Win 10 computer (running Windows Containers).

**The problem is that I am not able to make outgoing http requests from the web server inside Docker.**

I get the following error message:

> 'A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond'

Running the webserver in IIS Express works fine.

I have used Powershell to connect to the container hosting the image. Running "Test-NetConnection" returns the following output:

```
PS C:\inetpub\wwwroot> Test-NetConnection


ComputerName           : internetbeacon.msedge.net
RemoteAddress          : 13.107.4.52
InterfaceAlias         : Ethernet
SourceAddress          : 172.24.21.136
PingSucceeded          : True
PingReplyDetails (RTT) : 14 ms
```

**Test-NetConnection -port 80** fails after some time with this output:

```
PS C:\inetpub\wwwroot> Test-NetConnection -port 80
WARNING: TCP connect to (13.107.4.52 : 80) failed


ComputerName           : internetbeacon.msedge.net
RemoteAddress          : 13.107.4.52
RemotePort             : 80
InterfaceAlias         : Ethernet
SourceAddress          : 172.24.21.136
PingSucceeded          : True
PingReplyDetails (RTT) : 15 ms
TcpTestSucceeded       : False
```

If I open a different powershell window into the same container and run "netstat -an" to see active connections, the TCP request is visible:

```
Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
[...]
  TCP    172.24.21.136:49169    13.107.4.52:80         SYN_SENT
```

The State is "SYN_SENT" for the entire duration of the connection test.

I have tried setting the MTU as suggested in [Docker - Outgoing HTTPS requests timing out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55761359/docker-outgoing-https-requests-timing-out) but it did not work for me.

It is worth mentioning that I am working remotely, so I have an VPN connection (software), but it does not work even if I disconnect the VPN.

Am I missing something? 
I have tried creating an ASP.NET Core web app using the nanoserver image, but I the problem still exists. So I think the problem must be in my Docker/network configuration?

**Update:**

I tested running the same image on another computer which has neither VPN connection nor the same AV installed. "Test-NetConnection -port 80" worked instantly.

Here is Wireshark capture of successful test on different computer:
[image: Successful connection test]

Here is Wireshark capture of failing test on my computer:
[image: Failing connection test]

I see that the failing computer is using the same DNS server to find the ip for "internetbeacon.msedge.net" but after the response with IP 13.107.4.52, no TCP request is recorded from the container. On the working machine, this request is captured immediately after the DNS response.

Comment: Check firewall on your host computer and try to use a different computer. This is most likely caused by firewall/AV on your host

Comment: I don't believe it is a firewall issue on my host, as the "Test-NetConnection -port 80" works on the host. However, I have an AV that may be the issue. I'll try it on a different computer without the AV.

Comment: @GregorySuvalian I have now found in my Symantec traffic log that it blocks the request. I have raised the issue with the network admins now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check host firewall/AV as it's most likely the curlpit here

Comment: I uninstalled Symantec Endpoint Protection and I am now able to make external web calls from a docker container!